# Cannot find symbol R when Updating to Android 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cannot-find-symbol

Yesterday i updated Android to Android 3.1.3, everything was kinda good until, today when i created a new Empty Activity and on "AppCompatActivity" showed me the error "cannot find the symbol", so then I searched and I read it had something to do with the "build.gradle", so I've been updating the libraries and got different errors, the latest one is that object "R" cannot resolve symbol. So here what I've got.

I've had many attempts to solve it (as you can see the comments in the code) but so far i haven't solve it. Please Help me!

Also in one section Android suggested me to change in the gradle.properties # org.gradle.parallel=true from false, and it didn't work either.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha17'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            //name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

dependecies

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dell.getspeed"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'

    /*implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    /*implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.4.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.anastr:speedviewlib:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'*/
}
```

gralde-wrapper.propierties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

LOGS:
[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlYoZ.png)

Comment: Try to clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: Go to File > invalidate and restart and click on Invalidate and Restart

Comment: I've cleaned and rebuilt it but it didn't work @Ankita

Comment: I just did it, but didn't work @Priyank

Answer (score 0):

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

compileSdkVersion 27
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
```

File - Invalidate Caches/Restart - Invalidate and Restart

Comment: When adding this, the error still persists. and throw the logs updated on the post

Answer (score 0):

Close the current project and again reopen it and rebuild solution. Most of the time by rebuilding the solution, 
"R cannot resolve" problem can be solved.